# BASH Validating user input with specific options

Tags: bash

I need help in a piece of bash script that validates the user input.
The only options allowed are:

1. (a number) - ex.: 130
2. (two or three numbers separated by space) - ex: 130 165 199
3. (a range of numbers) - ex: 130-199
4. (a specific char) - ex: P

If other option is inserted then informs the user of invalid format and asks again for the input variable.
I've tried so many combinations but I'm not able to meet all the sentences.
My code bellow:

```
while ! [[ $INPUT  =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $INPUT  =~ ^[0~9]+" "+[0-9]+" "+[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $INPUT  =~ ^[0-9]+"-"+[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $INPUT = [Pp] ]]
    do printf "Invalid format!. Repeat input:\n"
      read INPUT
    done
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check operators' precedence (`!` vs. `||`)? You probably need parentheses here.

Comment: As @RenaudPacalet suggests, you need to put `()` around all the regexp tests because you're only negating the first one.

Comment: But the regexp for 3 numbers separated by space also isn't working

Comment: yes guys. it was the ().
Thank you for the help. Now for de 3 numbers with space regexp, it isn't working. I am going to search forward but if you have any clues, I'll apreciate.

Comment: about the 3 numbers with space regex, theres a typo in the expression. it should be ^[0-9] and not ^[0~9]   (~ instead of -).
thanks.

Comment: ^(\d{1,}[ ]){1,2}(\d){1,}$|^(\d){1,}-(\d){1,}$|^[pP]$